# When isn't inlining safe?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, scope, inline, compiler-optimization

I keep reading (for example in the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels) and other compilers) that inlining of functions isn't *always* safe. Could you please provide an example when inlining of functions shouldn't be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many languages, inlining a function will have no observable semantic effects, although it is likely to affect the compiled size and execution time of the program. However, that is not true in languages in which the call stack and/or local variable bindings are visible.

As a simple example, in Javscript the local variable [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) always refers to an array-like object containing the arguments to the current function call. Clearly, if the function in which it occurred were inlined, its semantics would change. An inliner would have to either refuse to inline a function whose body references `arguments` or it would have to modify the code in a way which preserved the semantics, possibly by creating another local variable with a different name and substituting the reference.

Another example would be the (non-recommended) use of [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Name lookup in the string passed to `eval` is done within the scope of the function which calls `eval`. For example:

```
inner = function(s) { var x = 4; return eval(s); }
outer = function(s) { var x = 3; return inner(s); }
outer("x+1")
```

Here the value returned by `outer` is `5`. If `inner` were inlined, which would require renaming its local variable `x` to avoid name conflict, the value returned would be `4`. (If both `inner` and `outer` were inlined, the value would probably be something else again.)

In general, it's going to be very difficult to inline a function which calls `eval` because there is no easy way to know the contents of the argument to `eval`.